# Correct tf setup for rviz for Android

Tags: android

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I'm trying to get rviz for Android running but my transform tree seems to be wrong, all the elements of the robot model are placed into coordinate system root.
The transform tree currently is /world -> /base_link -> other robot elements. Is this the correct way to do it?

Also rviz for Android only lets me choose "world" as the fixed frame, all the other elements in the transform tree do not show up (like they do in rqt, for example).

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/67945/correct-tf-setup-for-rviz-for-android/) by [bjoerngiesler](https://answers.ros.org/users/4267/bjoerngiesler/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2013-07-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Have you checked via [view_frames](http://www.ros.org/wiki/tf#view_frames) if there is only one and correct tree for all your transform frames?

Also you can run [roswtf](http://www.ros.org/wiki/roswtf) to check for anything mad. There is a [roswtf-tf-plugin](http://www.ros.org/wiki/tf#roswtf_plugin) that should be included automatically. I have seen that not to happen within groovy, but you'll see in the output.

---

And now that I tested *rviz-for-android* myself: The [documentation](https://bitbucket.org/zimmrmn3/rviz-for-android/wiki/Home) states the tf_throttle package must exist in the package path.

---

Originally posted by [felix k](https://answers.ros.org/users/606/felix-k/) with karma: 1650 on 2013-07-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [bjoerngiesler](https://answers.ros.org/users/4267/bjoerngiesler/) on 2013-07-21**:
Looks OK to me. Everything is connected under /world. roswtf complains about an additional entry in ROS_PACKAGE_PATH but that is all.